# how to use secure docker registry(by CA) for mesos container?

Tags: mesos, dcos

In DCOS, I want to deploy a mesos container with a self-defined image which stored in a local secure docker registry, and it has been secured by CA (not username and password!)

The json is

```
{
  "id": "/gpu-tflinker",
  "cmd": "while [ true ] ; do nvidia-smi; sleep 5; done",
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 1024,
  "gpus": 1,
  "instances": 1,
  "constraints": [
    [
      "hostname",
      "CLUSTER",
      "10.140.0.22"
    ]
  ],
  "container": {
    "type": "MESOS",
    "docker": {
      "image": "tflinker:test-gpu",
      "credential": null
    }
  }
}
```

The above json failed to run on marathon, and there is no content on mesos's stderr and stdout file, on mesos-agent log, the error message is :

```
E0721 05:01:57.726367 22498 slave.cpp:3976] Container 'e2c68720-0fb7-41bc-9d3b-a2b5e4793816' for executor 'gpu-t
flinker.b6f96725-6dd1-11e7-ba5d-0242b2c758c0' of framework 1079aaea-6dde-4dc1-8990-d926a895de78-0000 failed to s
tart: Unexpected HTTP response '401 Unauthorized' when trying to get the manifest
W0721 05:01:57.726478 22497 composing.cpp:541] Container 'e2c68720-0fb7-41bc-9d3b-a2b5e4793816' is already destr
oyed
I0721 05:01:57.726583 22497 slave.cpp:4082] Executor 'gpu-tflinker.b6f96725-6dd1-11e7-ba5d-0242b2c758c0' of fram
ework 1079aaea-6dde-4dc1-8990-d926a895de78-0000 has terminated with unknown status
I0721 05:01:57.726603 22497 slave.cpp:4193] Cleaning up executor 'gpu-tflinker.b6f96725-6dd1-11e7-ba5d-0242b2c75
8c0' of framework 1079aaea-6dde-4dc1-8990-d926a895de78-0000
I0721 05:01:57.726794 22497 slave.cpp:4281] Cleaning up framework 1079aaea-6dde-4dc1-8990-d926a895de78-0000
```

so it seems mesos failed to fetch the docker image. I've configed CA file for dockerd(move ca files to `/etc/docker/certs.d/`), so I can 'docker pull' the image to local machine, but I am not sure how to config CA file for mesos~
   in mesos-agent configurations, there exist a item `--docker_config=VALUE`, but it seems this item can only be used for username/password secured registry, I don't know how to config for CA secured registry.

anybody can help me out?!  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think CA file is just for encryption. you will need username and password in ca file way I think.

In my way, I put auth file into the container to authorize my private registry.

1. I wrote a web service for downloading the auth file 
   xxx.tar.gz(format: `.docker/config.json` in the tar.gz)
   in the config.json, `{"auths": {"test.com:6999": {"auth": "(username:password) [base64 encode]"}}}` like `{"auths": {"test.com:6999": {"auth": "Y2NjOjEyMw=="}}}`
2. use Mesos uris to download auth files prepared into the containers. then, it would authorized.

   `"uris":  [
      "http:your download url"
   ]`

Comment: But my private registry only secured by CA file,  no username and password.  Just put CA file under /etc/docker/[registry url]/ , and I can pull image from my registry, no need to execute 'docker login', so there is no config.json file under ~/.docker/

Comment: what's your docker version? what's your registry config `auth `? what's your docker config?